# How to compare 2 comma seperated string values and update in existing list at same position?

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a list of string which contains some value and I want to compare values of 2 positions from list and remove matching items from list.

**Code :**

```
var list = new List<string>();
 list.Add("Employee1");
 list.Add("Account");
 list.Add("100.5600,A+   ,John");
 list.Add("1.00000,A+     ,John");
 list.Add("USA");
```

Now i want to compare 2nd and 3rd position :

```
list.Add("100.5600,A+   ,John");
list.Add("1.00000,A+     ,John");
```

Compare above 2 records and remove matching records like below:

**Expected output :**

```
list.Add("100.5600");
list.Add("1.00000");
```

This is how i am trying to do :

```
 var source = list[2].Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim());
 var target = list[3].Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim());
 var result = source.Except(target);
```

But the problem is I am only getting `100.5600` as output.

Is it possible to compare and update non matching records in existing list?

Comment: for clarification. So you want actually to manipulate the original list and remove `A+      ,John` from the entries ?=!

Comment: @MongZhu Yeah exactly.I want to remove matching items 2nd and 3rd position by comparing values of those 2 positions

Comment: Split and trim before you add, problem solved. Actually, I don't think I understand what you are asking. What are your expected results, what are your actual results?

Comment: @Jodrell I have already mention expected output as well as my actual results.

Comment: can you please define **matching** ? the amount of spaces after `A+` is different in the 2 entiries. So practically only `John` is a match. But you want both substrings removed

Comment: also does the order of the substrings play a role? is this still a match between `"A+   ,John,100.5600"` and `"1.00000 ,A+     ,John"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this "beauty"

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Employee1");
list.Add("Account");
list.Add("100.5600,A+   ,John");
list.Add("1.00000,A+     ,John");
list.Add("USA");

//prepare the list, I decided to make a tuple with the original string in the list and the splitted array
var preparedItems = list.Select(x => (x, x.Split(',')));

//group the prepared list to get matching items for the 2nd and 3rd part of the split, I therefor used .Skip(1) on the previously prepared array
var groupedItems = preparedItems.GroupBy(x => string.Join(",", x.Item2.Skip(1).Select(y => y.Trim())));

//"evaluate" the group by saying if the items in the group is > 1 only use the first part of the prepared array and if it doesnt have more than one entry use the orignal string 
var evaluatedItems = groupedItems.SelectMany(x => x.Count() > 1 ? x.Select(y => y.Item2[0]) : x.Select(y => y.Item1));

//replace the orignal list with the new result
list = evaluatedItems.ToList();
```

**Edit - preserve original order:**

```
//extended the prepare routine with a third part the index to Keep track of the ordering of the original list
//so the tuple now consits of 3 parts instead of 2 - ([item], [index], [splittedArray])
var preparedItems = list.Select((x, i) => (x, i, x.Split(',')));

//changed to use Item3 intead of Item2 - since the Array now is on third position
var groupedItems = preparedItems.GroupBy(x => string.Join(",", x.Item3.Skip(1).Select(y => y.Trim())));

//instead of returning the simple string here already, return a tuple with the index (y.Item2) and the correct string
var evaluatedItems = groupedItems.SelectMany(x => x.Count() > 1 ? x.Select(y => (y.Item2, y.Item3[0])) : x.Select(y => (y.Item2, y.Item1)));

//now order by the new tuple x.Item1 and only return x.Item2
var orderedItems = evaluatedItems.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).Select(x => x.Item2);

list = orderedItems.ToList();


//one-liner - isn't that a beauty
list = list.Select((x, i) => (x, i, x.Split(','))).GroupBy(x => string.Join(",", x.Item3.Skip(1).Select(y => y.Trim()))).SelectMany(x => x.Count() > 1 ? x.Select(y => (y.Item2, y.Item3[0])) : x.Select(y => (y.Item2, y.Item1))).OrderBy(x => x.Item1).Select(x => x.Item2).ToList();
```

Comment: But i want to compare only 2nd and 3rd position so it that linq query comparing and manipulating only 2nd and 3rd position?

Comment: You have the only working solution using the entire original list. But I really hesitate to upvote it, because it is cryptic (unreadable) as hell and has no explanation....

Comment: @User Did you try it? I used `.Skip(1)` to move 1 place Forward, so only 2nd and 3rd Position are used (and 4th, 5th, 6th … xth if there are more).

Comment: `Skip(1)` leads to a narrow generalization. if the strings would match on the first position, your solution would not work anymore. I admit, that the post is very unclear about that

Comment: @MongZhu - now with explanation

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but this is manipulating the position of list i.e USA is on the last position but now it is coming at 2nd position.So i want to keep existing records position as it is

Comment: @User - yes, in fact this happens - I will think about a solution that can preserve the order - will come back to you

Comment: Thanks.Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You may get it easily by checking if items in one is not contained in the other:

```
   var result = source.Where(x => !target.Contains(x));
```

To update your old list:

```
  var source = string.Join(",", source.Where(x => !target.Contains(x)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering but I wanted to update existing list based on comparision instead of taking result in another variable.Is it possible?